# SonarSource Python alternative?

Tags: python, sonarqube

We are planing to place quality checking for our python code, earlier we used sonar for java projects. Is there any project support python having similar functionality of sonarsource ?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to [exist](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) a python plugin for sonar now.

Answer (score -1):

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296420/automatic-code-quality-review-tool-for-python

Basically you could use [PyFlakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes), [PyLint](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) or [PEP8](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and hook it to your version control system to run on every commit.

Answer (score -1):

You may have a look at [Violations Lib](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib). It is used in a bunch of plugins, listed in its README. It supports analysis tools for Python and there are plugins for commenting GitLab, Bitbucket Server and GitHub.

Comment: This is not a code analysis tool, it parses the reports (including the ones generated by Sonar)